# Show that $\angle AMB=\angle AMD$.

Tags: geometry

## Problem

Let $\omega$ be a circle inscribed in quadrilateral $ABCD$. The diagonal $AC$ intersects $\omega$ at two points $K$ and $L$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of the segment $KL$ . Show that $\angle AMB=\angle AMD$.

## Proof

As the figure shows, $\omega$ contacts $AB,BC,CD,DA$ at $U,V,W,Z$ respectivly. $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $X$. $O$ denotes the center of $\omega$.By Menelaus theorem, it's clear that $UZ,BD,VW$ are concurrent. Let the common point be $Y$. We may see that the polar lines of $A,C$ with respect to $\omega$ are $ZY,WY$ respectivly. Hence, the polar point of $AC$ with respect to $\omega$ is necessarily $Y$. Thus,$O,M,Y$ are collinear. Denote the intersection point of $AC$ and $YZ$ as $S$.Thus,$$(Y,X|B,D)=(AY,AX|AB,AD)=(AY,AS|AU,AZ)=(Y,S|U,Z)=-1.$$Notice that $MY \perp MX$. Therefore, $MX$,namely $AC$, bisects $\angle BMD$. This is exactly what we want to prove.

***AM I right? Any other solution?***

[image]

Comment: @Maxim Do you know the thing about so-called “polar point” and “polar line”?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$AZOU$ is cyclic by two opposite right angles, $AZOM$ is also cyclic by two opposite right angles, therefore $AZMU$ is cyclic.

From $\triangle AUM$ and $\triangle AZM$,
$$\frac {AU} {\sin \angle AMU} = \frac {AM} {\sin \angle AUM},
\frac {AZ} {\sin \angle AMZ} = \frac {AM} {\sin(\pi - \angle AUM)}, \\
\sin \angle AMU = \sin \angle AMZ,$$
therefore $\angle AMU = \angle AMZ$, since the sum of those angles is less than $\pi$. Similarly, $\angle VMC = \angle WMC$.

We have $\angle BUM = \pi - \angle AUM = \angle AZM = \pi - \angle DZM$ and similarly $\angle BVM = \pi - \angle DWM$. Then from $\triangle BUM, \triangle BVM, \triangle DZM, \triangle DWM$,
$$\frac {BU} {\sin \phi} = \frac {BM} {\sin \angle BUM},
\frac {BV} {\sin \psi} = \frac {BM} {\sin \angle BVM}, \\
\frac {DZ} {\sin \phi'} = \frac {DM} {\sin (\pi - \angle BUM)},
\frac {DW} {\sin \psi'} = \frac {DM} {\sin (\pi - \angle BVM)}, \\
\frac {BU} {\sin \phi} / \frac {DZ} {\sin \phi'} =
\frac {BV} {\sin \psi} / \frac {DW} {\sin \psi'}, \\
\sin \phi \sin \psi' = \sin \psi \sin \phi'.$$

Since $\psi' = \phi + \psi - \phi'$, this simplifies to $\sin(\phi + \psi) \sin(\phi - \phi') = 0$ and $\phi = \phi'$.